# Setting up Cucumber so it only passes or fails on rspec expectations (otherwise scenarios are pending)

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I want to distinguish between tests that make it to their assertion and tests that fail before the assertion and raise an error in the Given or When steps.

How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't this the default functionality of Cucumber?

Comment: Not the versions I'm using at least.

Comment: can you explain what you mean more specifically, or preferably give a code example?

Comment: You could always create your own HTML reporter using the JSON output of the suite, check the error message and have an icon display next to the scenario if it has failed due to an rspec  expectation, and a different icon in the case that it's a selenium error?